# Select STUFF() to simultaneously replace multiple characters in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have a big list of non redundant IDs and sequences as shown below (table A).

[image]

In a second table, I have multiple records of IDs, positions, and letters to be altered (table B).

[image]

What I would like to do is to replace specific letters in specific positions in the main sequence of table A based on the alterations that are given in the table B.

I'm trying to do it using the `STUFF()` function - an example of my query is provided below - but ideally I would like all the 4 changes of the proteinID `P12111` to be performed at the same time in the main sequence.

```
SELECT 
    A.[proteinID],
    STUFF(A.[proteinSeq], CAST(B.[position] AS INT), 1, B.[change_to] ) AS [proteinSeq]
FROM 
    [dbo].[TableA] A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [dbo].[TableB] B ON A.proteinID = B.proteinID
```

With the above query I'm getting 4 times the second sequence with one alteration at a time.

[image]

I'm not sure if I can achieve the requested output using `STUFF()`. On the other hand, I would like to avoid a `CURSOR` if possible. Any advice please?

Comment: I think a cursor here will not be the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE.  I'm a bit uncertain what `change_from` refers to -- either you change the value at the position or you don't.  In any case, the logic would seem to be:

```
with bb as (
      select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by proteinid order by seq) as seqnum
      from b
     ),
     cte as 
      select a.proteinid, a.seq, 1 as lev
      from a
      union all
      select cte.proteinid, stuff(a.seq, b.position, 1, b.change_to), lev + 1
      from cte join
           b
           on cte.lev = b.seqnum and
              cte.proteinid = a.proteinid
    )
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (partition by proteinid order by lev desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) cte
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH aa AS (
      -- get positions and how many times we need to make changes
      SELECT a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.proteinid order by a.seq) as seqnum
             , b.position
      from [dbo].[TableA] a
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
      [dbo].[Tableb] b on
      b.proteinid=a.proteinid

     ),
     cte AS
      (
      -- Get an anchor
      SELECT a.proteinid, a.seq, 1 AS lev
      FROM [dbo].[Tablea] a
      UNION ALL   
      -- CAST is needed to match the data types, choose yours as needed
      SELECT cte.proteinid, CAST(stuff(cte.seq, b.position, 1, b.changeto) AS VARCHAR(100)), lev + 1
      FROM cte 
      INNER JOIN aa
      ON cte.lev = aa.seqnum
      AND cte.proteinid = aa.proteinid
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableB] b
      ON cte.proteinid = b.proteinid
      AND aa.position=b.position
    )

SELECT * FROM cte
-- We filter as only need final change
WHERE cte.lev=
(SELECT MAX(t1.lev) FROM cte AS t1 
WHERE t1.proteinid=cte.proteinid)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `WHILE` instead of `CURSOR`.

Please find the demo [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b030a410f12bc0b4d9294796e75386ac).